# Smart way of preloading html email template using Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm sending out emails and I'd like to use HTML which is quite lengthy and currently in a file. What do people recommend doing as a way to reload it. The issue with local storage is that it might be costly to read from time wise. On the other hand including in a string/dictionary is possible but this is really messy. What is the recommended approach for storing say 10 HTML templates. I'd like to avoid a DB if I can.

Comment: while keeping the templates as files and setting up [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) properly, how long does it load? 100 slower than regular web page on the same server or worse?

Answer (score 2):

Template caching could be a possible improvement here. You can cache the whole template by using a [`cached.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) or different template [parts/fragments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching).

Also, consider using [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) with a [`template-timings`](https://github.com/orf/django-debug-toolbar-template-timings) panel to understand where the bottleneck is and where the time is spent:

> Template-timings is a panel for Django Debug Toolbar that gives an
>   in-dept breakdown of the time it takes to render your Django templates
>   (including templates included via {% extends %} and {% include %}).

Comment: does the cache will invalidate the cached template if the file is rewritten ?

Comment: @aRkadeFR I'm afraid it would not pick up the change until the cache is reseted, see also this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071221/resetting-cache-for-django-cached-template-loader).