# How do I reset template loader cache in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, django-templates

I used to be able to import `django.template.loader.template_source_loaders` and call `reset()` on all loaders to reset all template loader cache, but this no longer works.

How do I reset template loader cache in Django 1.9?

My settings, just in case this is useful:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True
    }
]
```

This is how I load my template:

```
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@never_cache
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def view(request, **kwargs):
    try:
        template = get_template('index.html')
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Run `make template`")

    return TemplateResponse(request, template)
```

I'm experiencing this issue on local dev using the built-in `runserver`, with DEBUG=True. The issue does not apply on production because the template will always exist.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the [cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader).

Comment: I don't use the cached template loader, but I do notice caching: it caches the non-existence of a template. When I then create the template, I have to restart the server to see a change.

Comment: @Blaise That is weird. I can't find any evidence of such caching in Django source code. [io.open is called every time, directly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py#L22).

Comment: @LudwikTrammer Maybe the problem is elsewhere? I updated my question to demonstrate how I load the template in my view.

Comment: Are you creating the template directories while the server is running, or just the templates? The [list of directories](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/template/utils.py#L113) will be cached

Comment: @Alasdair I was deleting and re-creating the folder, and this was indeed the problem. I'm now keeping the folder when I re-create `index.html` and it works fine now. Thanks for the help, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this question and answer are several years old. At the time it was written, Django did not cache its templates by default. Since then there have been several changes, e.g.

- Since [Django 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/3.2/#templates), templates cached using the cached template loader are correctly reloaded during development.
- Starting in [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#configuring-an-engine), Django started caching templates when `debug` is `False`.
- Starting in [Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#configuring-an-engine), Django started caching templates whatever the value of `debug`.

Here's my original answer from May 2016:

Django does not cache its templates, but it [does cache](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/template/utils.py#L113) the list of app template directories used by the app directories loader. If you create a new directory e.g. `polls/templates` after starting the server, then Django will not pick up templates in this directory until the server has been restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy:

```
from django.template.utils import get_app_template_dirs
get_app_template_dirs.cache_clear()
```

Comment: This will clear the app directory cache but not the template loader cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.template.loader import engines

for engine in engines.all():
    engine.engine.template_loaders[0].reset()
```

[Resetting cache for Django cached template loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071221/resetting-cache-for-django-cached-template-loader)