# Django cached template loader: exclude template from cache, or clear cache without restart

Tags: django, django-caching

I use Django's cached template loader to speed up my site:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        ....
    )),
)
```

Is there a way to exclude specific templates from being cached? I have a template that I change a fair amount and I'd like to avoid having to restart my project every time I make a change to the template. Or, maybe a way to clear all cached templates without restarting the project?

I did see this [Resetting cache for Django cached template loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071221/resetting-cache-for-django-cached-template-loader). Maybe that can be used to exclude a template but, if so, I'm not seeing how to use it.

Edit: Someone asked if this answered my question [Fighting client-side caching in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095520/fighting-client-side-caching-in-django/). No, because my question has nothing to do with client-side caching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fighting client-side caching in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095520/fighting-client-side-caching-in-django)

Comment: No. My question has nothing to do with client-side caching.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm facing the same problem, and even after diving into Django's source code I can't find a way to get my hands on a django.template.loaders.cached.Loader to call .reset() on it, although that loader seems to be the default loader loaded

Comment: Nevermind, this solved a different version of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57827629/6141224